# Unable to run java program with a classpath in a file and usage of @ on the cli

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-interface

I came across a strange behavior when executing a java program from command line with a classpath in a file. I'm not sure if this is related to Windows, Java or the cli.

Test class:

```
package de.test;

public class Playground {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }

}
```

After compiling I can run it with the command

```
java -classpath "C:\Users\TEST\eclipse-workspace\Playground\target\classes" de.test.Playground
```

However, if I have a file `cp.txt` with the content (this is only the classpath argument)

```
-classpath "C:\Users\TEST\eclipse-workspace\Playground\target\classes"
```

and I run

```
java "@cp.txt" de.test.Playground
```

I get the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.test.Playground`. Same without quotes around `@cp.txt`.

I tested this with Oracle JDK 11.0.2 and OpenJDK 11.0.5. Both show the same behavior.

Does anyone know why this happens? Whenever the classpath is too long, Eclipse puts it in a file and uses the @ command line to run the program. But this doesn't work as shown above. So whenever I have too many dependencies I'm no longer able to run a Java program from within Eclipse.

Comment: What is this? `"@cp.txt"` is this a JDK 11 new feature?

Comment: I have no idea where it comes from. Saw it the first time when I tried hours to figure out why Eclipse won't run my code any more.

Comment: I think in java 11 you can do this: `java Playground.java` and it will get compiled automatically

Comment: I don't need a workaround. Compiling the code is not a problem. And I can run it as shown in my question. But that doesn't help me.

Comment: @ACV: [it was added in 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR-GUID-4856361B-8BFD-4964-AE84-121F5F6CF111) but 9 and 10 are now EOL so 11 is the oldest supported release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **command-line argument file** `cp.txt` **escape** backslashes (**`\`**) by replacing them with double backslashes (`\\`) or use forward slashes (`/`) instead of backslashes (`\`).

See [The java Command - java Command-Line Argument Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html#java-command-line-argument-files):

> - Because backslash (`\`) is an escape character, a backslash character    must be escaped with another backslash character.

Comment: Great, that's it. Thank you. I'm gonna create a bug ticket for Eclipse.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why does the first example work? It contains unescaped backslashes as well.

Comment: The command line is being processed by Windows CMD, in contrast to the command-line argument file which is read directly by Java.

Comment: For reference: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558495 Unfortunately they still have no way to provide hotfixes for critical issues. I guess it's about time to use another IDE if people at Eclipse foundation insist on this  questionable process.

Comment: The Eclipse foundation only hosts projects but does not have developers (in contrast to Mozilla; similar to Apache). Just upgrade to an integration or to a milestone build where the fix is already available. Better than hotfixes (which in my view are a hack for a broken process) is to test milestone builds and report bugs before a release. However, due to the quarterly release, fewer people (especially on Windows) do this than before. Please make Eclipse better by using milestones builds and by reporting bugs.